# MySQL JOIN 2 tables and get sum for both tables separately

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables. I need get revenue from two tables - sum revenue with same date and with same user_id (output is in chart - dashboard for each user).

I created a SQL query which works fine, BUT from the second table I getting revenues from all users, I need show revenues only for each user separately and if user_id with date exist in table. I want to mention that every user does not have rows in the 2 tables, only users which uses this service. see below:

TABLE: user_revenue

```
USER_ID                CDATE             REVENUE
1                      2019-03-15        15
2                      2019-03-15        18
5                      2019-03-15        29
9                      2019-03-15        11
```

TABLE: user_revenue_publisher

```
USER_ID                CDATE             REVENUE
1                      2019-03-15        15
1                      2019-03-15        50
9                      2019-03-15        21
9                      2019-03-15        18
```

MY SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT  a.user_id,
        a.cdate,
        a.revenue,
        SUM(b.revenue) as total_revenue
FROM    user_revenue a
           INNER JOIN user_revenue_publisher b
                ON a.cdate = b.cdate
WHERE   a.user_id=$id AND a.cdate >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) group by cdate asc

($id = is ID user after login)
```

I need to combine these queries into one:

```
$result = $pdo->query("select * from user_revenue where user_id=$id AND `cdate` >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)"); 
$result2 = $pdo->query("select * from user_revenue_publisher where user_id=$id AND `cdate` >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)");
```

MY WRONG SQL:

```
USER_ID                CDATE             REVENUE
1                      2019-03-15        80 (correct)
```

```
USER_ID                CDATE             REVENUE
2                      2019-03-15        104 (BAD value, I need sum = 18)
```

I NEED RESULT:

```
USER_ID                CDATE             REVENUE
1                      2019-03-15        80
```

```
USER_ID                CDATE             REVENUE
2                      2019-03-15        18
```

and for new user eg.USER_ID = 24 which is new registred should be

```
USER_ID                CDATE             REVENUE
24                     2019-03-15        0
```

I am glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues: The GROUP BY needs all the columns that are not aggregate functions (like the `SUM()`. Also, you show two `REVENUE` columns in your query, but only one in your examples, so it's hard to tell which one is the problem (although I would assume it's the sum()).

I think this should give you what you want:

```
   SELECT  a.user_id,
        a.cdate,
        a.revenue,
        SUM(b.revenue) AS total_revenue
           FROM    user_revenue a
           INNER JOIN user_revenue_publisher b
                 ON a.cdate = b.cdate
        WHERE a.user_id= $id  group by a.User_ID,a.revenue, a.cdate
```

Comment: Thanks, but SQL still dont work correctly. When I login as new user I see sum revenues from all users, why? in php foreach I have foreach($result as $row){
$final_revenue = $row['revenue'] + $row['total_revenue']; Please can you create a new sql instead? I think that my SQL is fully bad.

Comment: I need only sum revenue from one table and second table with same day and user_id for last 30 days. Classic chart with revenues for last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users that have no revenue, then you need an outer join (or correlated subquery).  So, I would suggest:

```
select ur.user_id, ur.cdate, ur.revenue,
       ur.revenue + coalesce(sum(urp.revenue), 0) as total_revenue
from user_revenue ur left join
     user_revenue_publisher urp
     on urp.cdate = ur.cdate and
        urp.user_id = ur.user_id
where ur.user_id = ? and
      ur.cdate >= curdate() - interval 30 day
 group by ur.user_id, ur.cdate, ur.revenue;
```

Notes:

- The `= $id` suggests that you are munging the query string with a literal value.  The `?` means -- **use parameters**.
- Use *meaningful* table aliases, so the query is easier to follow.
- You need a `left join` to keep all rows in the first table, even when there are no rows in the second.
- As a consequence, you need to handle the `NULL` values that might result.

Comment: Thanks, SQL works, but still have some problems. When I login as a new user I see sum revenues from all users from table user_revenue_publisher, why?                                                                                                                       
in php foreach I have foreach($result as $row) { 
$final_revenue = $row['revenue'] + $row['total_revenue'];   }

Comment: I need only sum revenue from one table and second table with same day and user_id for last 30 days. Classic chart with revenues for last 30 days.

Comment: I tried use: where ur.user_id =$id  and urp.user_id=$id , but this shows only day if user has row in second table user_revenue_publisher and not others days with revenues which is wrong.

Comment: I need to combine these queries into one:                                                       
```$result = $pdo->query("select * from user_revenue where user_id=$id AND `cdate` >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)"); 
$result2 = $pdo->query("select * from user_revenue_pub where user_id=$id AND `cdate` >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)");```